# Opening a file in external app using the path

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app where the user can pick a file or image to add to a support ticket. I want the user to be able to view the file/image again once they click on it again.

So if they click on a PDF file, it opens the PDF viewer app. And if they click on a txt file, it opens an app that can handle txt files.

I have the path of the file, it's in the `tmp` directory. How do I do that?

---

**P.S :** No, I don't want to open/view the file `inside` my app.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you can make use of LaunchServices:

[LSOpenCFURLRef](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1442850-lsopencfurlref)

EDITED:

On iOS, this should do the trick:

[UIApplication.shared.open(url, open, completionHandler)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open)

Comment: I think that is a MacOS function, since it says it's available on MacOS and not iOS

Comment: Ahh, I missed that it's iOS. Then what about UIApplication.shared.open(url, ...)?